# how to start atom (-editor) from command line (terminal)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I installed the editor Atom as snap. Normally i can start Atom from command line by typing `atom .` but after reinstalling my Ubuntu system I get an error:

> nohup: failed to run command '/tmp/troubadix/atom-build/Atom/atom': No such
> file or directory

Every other program installed via Snap or Deb starts from terminal just fine.

Comment: Did you install atom in “/tmp/troubadix/atom-build”?  Most likely, /tmp has been reformatted or simply a tmpfs and doesn’t survive a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I can start Atom from terminal with

```
snap run atom
```

The easiest workaround is to make a shell aliases:

```
alias atom='snap run atom'
```

Answer (score 0):

Some well meaning person with zero actual sense decided to call the atom snap "snappyatom". So now you have to use `snap run snappyatom` to make it work. Augh. :P

Please, folks. Leave the original application names alone for your snap packages! Package managers should vanish into the woodwork, and stuff like this does not make people like snaps any better!